# Función se ejecuta cuando quiero condicionarla

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Soy relativamente nuevo programando y aún hay un par de cosas que ignoro y paso por alto y esta es una de ellas...
Estoy haciendo una app con react native y expo, el asunto aquí es que tengo una función que regresa true o false dependiendo sea el caso el problema aquí es que cuando yo quiero tomar la función y hacer un console log o hacer una condicional la función se ejecuta nuevamente mi pregunta es ¿Existe alguna manera de que la función no se ejecute cuando le estoy haciendo un console.log o en una condicional con if? Esta es mi función :

```js
const register = (name, username, email, password, confirmpassword) => {
    let boleano = null
            axios.post('/signup', {
                name: name,
                username: username,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }) .then(response => {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('user-token', response.data.data.token)
                boleano = true
            }) .catch(error => {
                boleano = false
                Alert.alert(error.response.data.message)
            })
        if(boleano == true ){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        
    }
```

Y pretendo llamarla aquí, no está de más mencionar que las funciones las estoy importando desde otro fichero js:

```js
registro = async() => {
    if(this.state.sendform == false ){
      this.setState({sendform : true})
      await funciones.register(this.state.name,this.state.username,
                  this.state.email, this.state.password,                     this.state.confirmpassword)
      this.setState({sendform : false})
      console.log(funciones.register()) //Aqui se ejecuta de nuevo
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jaja descubrí a prueba y error que si la función la guardo en una constante o variable y luego uso esa constante para comparar esta no se ejecuta nuevamente ¿Estoy en lo correcto?